# angular binding numbers array to plain bootstrap multiselect value (reactive forms)

Tags: angular, multi-select

In angular html template I have multiselect (plain bootstrap multiselect) like in html here:

```html
<form [formGroup]="globalScriptForm">
...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="events">Events</label>
    <select multiple class="form-select"
            type="text"
            id="events"
            formControlName="events">
       <option value=0>a</option>
       <option value=1>b</option>
       <option value=2>c</option>
     </select>
  </div>
...
</form>
```

and here is code from controller:

```js
export class GlobalScriptEditComponent implements OnInit {
  globalScriptForm!: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let events: number[] = [0,1];
    this.globalScriptForm = new FormGroup({
      'events': new FormControl(events),
    });
  }
}
```

Question would be how can I make multi-select options in html template **selected** based on values in events array from controller, e.g. [0,1]?

i.e. get this result in html (notice word **selected** next to options 0 and 1, as these are values in array)

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="events">Events</label>
    <select multiple class="form-select"
            type="text"
            id="events"
            formControlName="events">
      <option value=0 selected>a</option>
      <option value=1 selected>b</option>
      <option value=2>c</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Hope it is somehow clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share a MVCE

Comment: not sure what MVCE is, but I enhanced the explanation above (at least I believe my explanation is better now, ). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list of options should be added to ts file:

```
optionsList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

and it should be used in html file like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="globalScriptForm">
...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="events">Events</label>
    <select multiple class="form-select"
            type="text"
            id="events"
            formControlName="events">
       <option *ngFor="let option of optionsList; let i = index" [value]="i">{{option}}</option>
     </select>
  </div>
...
</form>
```

instead of hardcoding it (as presented above).

Everything else should not be changed.
Turned out to be simple solution after all